# Conditional .filter() function with different filters

Tags: javascript, filter

I have an array of people:

```
let people = [{
    name: 'John',
    sex: 'M',
    hasHouse: 'Yes',
    hasCar: 'Yes'
  },
  {
    name: 'Carl',
    sex: 'M',
    hasHouse: 'No',
    hasCar: 'No'
  },
  {
    name: 'Lisa',
    sex: 'F',
    hasHouse: 'Yes',
    hasCar: 'No'
  },
  {
    name: 'Mary',
    sex: 'F',
    hasHouse: 'Yes',
    hasCar: 'Yes'
  },
  {
    name: 'David',
    sex: 'M',
    hasHouse: 'No',
    hasCar: 'Yes'
  }
]
```

I need to be able to filter the original array based in one, several or all properties, So for example I could have a variable for each property of each object

```
let filter = {name: 'sex',value: 'M'};
let filterTwo = {name: 'hasCar',value: 'Yes'};
let filterThree = {name: 'hasHouse',value: 'Yes'};
// The value would be changed by the user
```

And then just use a filter function:

```
let filtered = people.filter(person => person[filter.name] === filter.value && person[filterTwo.name] === filterTwo.value && person[filterThree.name] === filterThree.value);
```

The problem is that it doesnt work if you only want use only one filter (filter will be comparing with null in unselected filters). There's also the fact that I feel the code is not efficient enough and it could be done better.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can put the filters in an array and use `.every`:

```js
let filters = [
    { name: "sex", value: "M" },
    { name: "hasCar", value: "Yes" },
    { name: "hasHouse", value: "Yes" },
];

people.filter(v => filters.every(f => v[f.name] === f.value));
```

If you don't want to use a filter, you can take it out of the array.

Answer (score 1):

i think you can have a map for filters like this

```js
const people = [{
    name: 'John',
    sex: 'M',
    hasHouse: 'Yes',
    hasCar: 'Yes'
  },
  {
    name: 'Carl',
    sex: 'M',
    hasHouse: 'No',
    hasCar: 'No'
  },
  {
    name: 'Lisa',
    sex: 'F',
    hasHouse: 'Yes',
    hasCar: 'No'
  },
  {
    name: 'Mary',
    sex: 'F',
    hasHouse: 'Yes',
    hasCar: 'Yes'
  },
  {
    name: 'David',
    sex: 'M',
    hasHouse: 'No',
    hasCar: 'Yes'
  }
];

const filterOn = (arr, filters) => {
    return Object.keys(filters).reduce((acc, k) => {
    return acc.filter(item => {
        return item[k] === filters[k];
    });
    }, arr);
};


console.log(filterOn(people, { hasHouse: 'Yes', hasCar: 'Yes'}));
```